# Best WiFi Solution for full coverage

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I have a large area that needs to be covered by WiFi- I need some guidance:

I have the Netgear Nighthawk MR60 Mesh system with 2 "Sattelites" and a (cheap) fios router in the basement.

Currently my setup is like this: modem---fios router---MR60 router---satellite---satellite

Since the fios router is weak and in the basement- I set it as "Network 1" on 2.4ghz and 5ghz; I have a cable that connects from the basement router to the attic and connected the MR60 to that and put the satellites on the main floor and even back to the basement because the fios router is faulty in the wireless connections.

I would have liked to put the mesh router in AP Bridge Mode, but I couldn't find it in the settings; so now there is "Network 2".

I also would like to throw the fios router in the lake, and just use the MR60  through and through- but I have a nest and camera system that needs ports to connect to the router (The MR60 only has 1 lan port).

Since I know that this is a horrible setup I will leave you guys to advise me on ho I should set up the wireless system.

To make this a more objective question, Is there a way to use the MR60 Mesh System as an extender of a source router.

P.S. Does 5ghz really make a difference if you only pay for 80mbps network?

Comment: Yes, 5 GHz does make a difference: the shorter wavelength is more easily blocked, so is shorter range in a house. *Theoretically*, close to the modem, throughput could be high, but the 80 Mbps connection is the limitation for both bands. BTW, same is true for 5G high-frequency phones... more cells are needed to cover the same area.

Comment: Your post may have a specific question, but the title, and most of the post, are asking for opinions and recommendations, both of which are off topic here. Please edit your question (and it's title) to focus it, make it more clear, and on topic.